# PHP preg_match and replace multiple instances between tags

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, str-replace, preg-match-all

Sorry if the title is a little confusing its hard to explain so will try my best :)

Ok I have a blog and in the back end I want to be able to add multiple galleries for each product in a post

Example blog:

```
Some Product Title 1
blah blah blah blah
[Gallery::product_id_01]

Some Product Title 2
blah blah blah blah
[Gallery::product_id_02]
```

So in this example, there are 2 products each with a Gallery tag.
I want to be able to find and replace these example tags `[Gallery::product_id_01]` and `[Gallery::product_id_02]`
with the actual image gallery, which is done via a php function called `ProdImgGallery()` this passes the same ID example: `product_id_01`

The tags will always have `[Gallery::*]` but the text after the :: indicated by * will be different and needs to be captured from the tag for the next stage.

Using `preg_match_all("/\[Gallery::([^\]]*)\]/", $blog_content, $product_id);` finds all the tags as you would expect but I then need to replace the tags with the correct gallery indicated by its unique ID

This is as far as I can get but this just fetches each gallery based on all the ids found by `preg_match_all` I cant figure out how to replace each one with the corresponding gallery

```
//Find all Matches and put in array    
preg_match_all("/\[Gallery::([^\]]*)\]/", $blog_content, $product_id);

//Count all matches
$all_matches = count($product_id[1]);

//Loop through them
for($x=0;$x<$all_matches;$x++)
{
echo $product_id[1][$x]."<br>";
$prod_img_gallery = ProdImgGallery($product_id[1][$x]);
}
$blog_content = preg_replace("/\[Gallery::([^\]]*)\]/",$prod_img_gallery,$blog_content);
```

Hope this makes some kind of sense, I have trouble explaining things so please forgive me :)
I did try searching too but could not find an answer that matched my exact problem

Many thanks!

Comment: is this PHP? If so, it will be helpful if you use the tag PHP

Additional question:  Why can't you use "[Gallery::product_id_01]" as your regular expression? e.g.
for(...) {
  $target_id=sprintf("/\[Gallery::product_id_%02d\]/", id);
}

Comment: @Popeye hi sorry im a noob here and didnt realise - my bad - I cant use "[Gallery::product_id_01]" as this will be dynamic

Comment: i am sorry that i hit save button earlier than I finished my --answer-- question. I do understand the point of being random. Can you give me a real example of your random line?

Comment: @Popeye I have said in the post its will be like '[Gallery::product_id_02]' but the id after '::' will be dynamic so for example in the back end when writting the blog I click a button and it will add '[Gallery::] ' I just then enter the product id for example '[Gallery::product_id_02] ' I would be adding say about 10 products on a blog post so there will be a set of 10 of these codes all with unique ids - hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$input = "Some Product Title 1
blah blah blah blah
[Gallery::product_id_01]

Some Product Title 2
blah blah blah blah
[Gallery::product_id_02]";

$out = preg_replace_callback(
    "/\[Gallery::(.*?)\]/", function($m) {
                                $val = "[Gallery::" . ProdImgGallery($m[1]) . "]";
                                return $val;
                            },
    $input);
echo $out;
```

The idea here is to capture every occurrence of `[Gallery::...]`, and than pass the captured group into a callback function.  The above script uses an inline anonymous function for the callback, which then returns the replacement you want, using the `ProdImgGallery()` function.

Comment: many thanks after a little play with this its works!!! - I have to edit `$val = "[Gallery::" . ProdImgGallery($m[1]) . "]";` to `$val = ProdImgGallery($m[1]) ;` to remove the [Gallery part as it was appearing as text. I will do a full test to make sure - Thank you :)